# Tensor product of two irreducible representations over $\mathbb R$ is not irreducible

Tags: representation-theory

> Let $G$ and $H$ be finite groups and $V$, $W$ - their corresponding finite-dimensional irreducible representations over the field $\mathbb R$. Is it true that tensor product $V \otimes W$ as a representation of direct product $G \times H$ is irreducible? If not, what number of subrepresentations it has in its direct sum decomposition?

I can show that over $\mathbb R$ tensor product of irreducible representations can be not irreducible: if $G$ and $H$ are finite cyclic groups, then they both have $\mathbb R^2$ as irreducible representations, and its tensor product is not irreducible since its dimension is 4, but every irreducible representation of finite abelian group over $\mathbb R$ has dimension 1 or 2.

But what about general case. What tensor product direct decomposition can look like?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know already that, over $\mathbb{C}$, the tensor product of irreducible representations is irreducible as a representation of the product?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Yes, it follows from density theorem.

Comment: $\langle\chi_V,\chi_V\rangle$ and $\langle\chi_W,\chi_W\rangle$ are either $1$, $2$, or $4$, depending on the decompositions of $V \otimes \mathbb{C}$ and $W \otimes \mathbb{C}$ as complex representations of $G$ and $H$, respectively (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2594940/19006)). You can check that $$\langle \chi_{V \otimes W}, \chi_{V \otimes W} \rangle = \langle {\chi_V, \chi_V} \rangle \langle \chi_W, \chi_W \rangle.$$
Now I think you can proceed by case analysis to figure out what $V \otimes W$ has to look like? Tbh not sure this'll work but it might be worth a shot.